# Vinculação de Objeto

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e me deparei com o seguinte “problema”:

```
@RequestMapping("/pagamentos")
public ModelAndView pagamentos(FormaPagamento pagamento){       
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("cadastro-pagametos");        
    return model;
}
```

Tenho uma classe chamada FormaPagamento e envio um objeto desse tipo para a minha JSP
para vincular ele ao meu formulário de cadastro.
Porém é reportado o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object 
for bean name 'pagamento' available as request attribute
```

Pelo que consegui identificar o “problema” é por causa do nome da minha classe FormaPagamento, caso eu renomeie a classe para Pagamento funciona normalmente.

Alguém sabe o pqe disso acontecer?

Na JSP que faço esse cadastro eu acabo fazendo o cadastro de outras 3 coisas.
Mais a parte do pagamento é essa:

Meu MODAL com o form do cadastro:

```
 <!-- MODAL DE CADASTRO DE FORMAS DE PAGAMENTO -->
<div class="modal fade" id="pagamento" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">PAGAMENTO</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form:form id="formFormaPagamento" action="${s:mvcUrl('CC#cadastroPagamentos').build()}" method="POST" commandName="pagamento">
          <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">                                                         
                        <form:input cssClass="form-control" name="id" path="id" id="id" type="hidden" readonly="true"/>
                        <h5>Forma de Pagamento:</h5>
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <form:input type="text" cssClass="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" path="nome"/>
                        </div>  
                        <br>          
                        <div class="botao">                                         
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><i class="far fa-save"></i> SALVAR</button>                
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

          </form:form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Meu Controller é esse:

```
    @RequestMapping("/cadastros")
    public ModelAndView cadastros(Marca marca, Categoria categoria, Motivo motivo, Pagamento pagamento) {
       ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("tela-cadastros");     
       model.addObject("marcas", marcaDAO.lista());
       model.addObject("categorias", categoriaDAO.lista());
       model.addObject("pagamentos", pagamentoDAO.lista());
       model.addObject("descartes", motivoDAO.lista());
       return model;
}
```

Percebam que o **FormaPagamento** já está alterado para **Pagamento** sendo que dessa forma funciona e da outra não.

Minha classe está assim:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="mejt_tbl_cad_pagamentos")
  public class Pagamento {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      private int id;
      @Column(length=15,nullable=false)
      private String nome;

      public Pagamento() {}

      public Pagamento(int id, String nome) {
         this.id = id;
         this.nome = nome;
      }

      public int getId() {
         return id;
      }

      public void setId(int id) {
         this.id = id;
      }

      public String getNome() {
         return nome;
      }

      public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
      } 

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return "FormaPagamento [id=" + id + ", nome=" + nome + "]";
      }
  }
```

Comment: Vc pode compartilhar o seu JSP e FormaPagamento?

Comment: Informa o código da jsp que envia os dados de pagamento para o controller para conseguirmos verificar melhor.

Comment: Editei e adicionei o JSP, Controller e Class.